# Ionic 3, editable Select

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

How I can obtain an editable textbox inside dropdown in ionic 3? ion-select does not allow to add editable input inside list. Or is there anyway to use PopoverController with dropdown style?

Image may clear my requirement more.

[image]

or

[image]

Comment: I recommend you to make modal page which **seems like** dropdown style.

Comment: Yes, that should be the better solution. Thank you.